# Django, Integrity error on self referring model and weird postgres behavior

Tags: django, postgresql, foreign-keys, self-reference

I have the following model:

```py
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    milking = models.BooleanField(help_text=GroupHelpTexts.MILKING)
    sub_groups = models.ForeignKey('self',
                                   on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
                                   blank=True)
    herd = models.ForeignKey(on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             to=Herd)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

When I'm trying to add a new group in the admin I get the following error:

```
IntegrityError at /admin/farm_api/group/add/
null value in column "sub_groups_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (5, milking 1, t, 1, null).
```

This is the first problem.

The second one is that the DB shows this table as empty (At least when accessed from pg admin 4)

```
SELECT * from farm_api_group;
```

outputs an empty table and when I validated from the shell:

```py
from farm_api.models.group_models import Group
q = Group.objects.all()
print(len(q))
0
print(q)
<QuerySet []>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set [**`null=True`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#null) since there will not be any ***`sub_groups`*** when you create a *"first"* `Group` instance.

```
class Group(models.Model):
    sub_groups = models.ForeignKey('self',
                                   on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
                                   blank=True,
                                   null=True)
    # other code
```